# SQL Sever 2014 not importing all rows

Tags: sql-server

Amateur here. I'm importing 8 `.csv` files into a SQL Server table via the Management Studio import/export wizard.

On file 7 and everything has gone swimmingly until here. There are 5,000,000 rows in the file (every file has a confirmed 5 million rows). However, the import wizard is only importing ~ 1,500,000. It finishes with the success message and no errors. The final report gives no indication anything went wrong.

I have removed the 200,000 rows around the row the import is ending on. The file still stops at ~ 1.5M.

Any ideas on what kinds of things may cause the wizard to "successfully" import only a percentage of records without errors? Any way to derive the reason from the transaction log?

I appreciate any and all feedback. Thanks!

Comment: I should add that I tried importing file 7 into its own table and the same number of rows were imported.

Comment: How do you know that file 7 has 5 million rows? Have you counted the rows in all the files using another program/tool/application?

Comment: That's the number quoted to me from the source. I have not been able to independently verify that number. But, every file has been spot on. And I will add that this file is in the same format and layout as those files and sports the same file size at 1.5gb (all files are within 80 or so mb of each other)

Comment: use `ultraedit` or `notepad++` to check by yourself how many rows are there

Comment: I was able to verify the row count as 5,000,000 with ultra edit. I can't see any irregularities with the row the import is ending on.

Comment: In absence of any other ideas, cut out rows from 140000 to 160000 and import them. In this way you can work out if the issue is some kind of hard row number limit or if it something to do with the data

Comment: What effective rows are imported? Effectively the first 1.5M rows in the `csv`-file? Or is it random?

Comment: It is importing the first 1.5M rows. And I did try deleting 100,000 rows on each side of the stopping point using ultraedit and re-uploaded. The upload is still "successfully" stopping at ~ 1.5M.

Comment: No one else has any ideas?